# Azure ZRS/GRS vs snapshots

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Why would I need to create a blob snapshot and incur additional cost if Azure already provides GRS(Geo redundant storage) or ZRS (Zone redundant storage)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redundancy (ZRS/GRS/RAGRS) provides means to achieve high availability of your resources (blobs in your scenario). By enabling redundancy you are ensuring that a copy of your blob is available in another region/zone in case primary region/zone is not available. It also ensures against data corruption of the primary blob.

When you take a snapshot of your blob, a readonly copy of that blob in its current state is created and stored. If needed, you can restore a blob from a snapshot. This scenario is well suited if you want to store different versions of the same blob.

However, **please keep in mind that neither redundancy nor snapshot is backup** because if you delete base blob, all the snapshots associated with that blob are deleted and all the copies of that blob available in other zones/regions are deleted as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to understand the difference between **Backup** and **Redundancy**.

Backups make sure if something is lost, corrupted or stolen, that a copy of the data is available at your disposal.

Redundancy makes sure that if something fails—your computer fails, a drive gets fried, or a server freezes and you are able to work regardless of the problem. Redundancy means that all your changes are replicated to another location. In case of a failover, your slave can theoretically function as a master and serve the (hopefully) latest state of your file system.

Comment: Yes. Guess i should have read this post.:) 
 https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/346907/backups-vs.-redundancy-what%25E2%2580%2599s-the-difference/amp/

Comment: Only problem with this answer is that snapshot is not a backup :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also turn soft delete on.  That would keep a copy of every blob for every change made to it, even if someone deletes it.  Then you set the retention period for those blobs so they would be automatically removed after some period of time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-soft-delete